# Finding columns count of a range

Tags: excel, vba, count

Below is some Excel VBA code that is supposed to print the column count of the range that is specified in the string. I am getting an error in the `Debug.Print` section. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim val1a As String
val1a = "A1:D1"

Dim Rng1 As Range

Debug.Print Rng1(var1a).Columns.Count  ' error here
```

Comment: We have both `val1a` and `var1a` in the code above. Hopefully that's just a typo here and not in the real code. In future use `Option Explicit` to ensure that variables are declared before being used

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
Range(var1a).Columns.Count
```

Comment: Thank you.  I should have seen that. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake you did was,

you declared 'val1a' but calling 'var1a'.

correct the typo and you'll be able to get that.